# Why didn't the Doppler know the answers to these questions?

Tags: the-witcher

The Doppler claimed, after taking the form of Mousesack, that everything Mousesack had known belonged to them. And indeed, Doppler-Mousesack displayed knowledge of certain facts, such as that Mousesack had intended to take Ciri to Geralt. However, when Ciri confronted the Doppler in the form of Mousesack with questions about Mousesack's past, the former was unable to answer them all correctly.

Did the Doppler actually acquire Mousesack's memories, or was that merely boasting? If so, why could they not answer Ciri's questions?

Comment: Having the memory that Mousesack has arthritis and guessing that he'd feel uncomfortable in the cold, would probably be non trivial.

Comment: Why wouldn't the Dopple remember that Mousesack felt uncomfortable in the cold, though?

Comment: It seemed, from how his ability was displayed, that he had to exert some effort and 'search' the memories foreign to his own personality. It took him a moment to answer earlier questions, after all. Since Ciri put such a seemingly innocent question, the unnerved Dopple did not care to double-check (pun intended) and fell into the trap. This is conjecture based upon my impressions only, though, hence comment only.

Comment: @Adamant I guess the reason is given by Philip's comment, but I also cannot substantiate it at the moment.

Comment: Had the same question myself when I saw it.

Comment: She also seems to be grating on the Doppler's nerves a fair bit by that point and it seems like maybe they were questioning their decision to take the contract in the first place. Maybe it was an unconscious slip, or maybe it was the doppler figuring it would be easier to just be exposed and do things the hard way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked [the Witcher wiki page on Dopplers](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Doppler) but it didn't say whether or not this was something Dopplers could do. The rest of this answer is based solely on the episode in question.

From what I say, the Doppler definitely has Mousesack's memories; he demonstrates this earlier, by knowing why Mousesack wanted to kill himself, and that he'd stolen Queen Calanthe's scarf. Later, when he impersonates Cahir, he remarks about Cahir's thoughts, about how he is delusional for believing in the White Flame:

> Do you really believe all this nonsense in your head? This prophecy?

When responding to Ciri's questions, he fails for a few reasons. For the first question "did you ever stop missing Skellige", I think he likely answers correctly, but too simply; he thinks for a moment and says "I was very homesick". This is probably true, Mousesack probably was homesick when leaving Skellige. The part that's missing is his love for Cintra, and how it became his home; Ciri didn't ask for this information specifically, but it's something Mousesack wouldn't leave out of his answer.

For the second question, "do you miss the cold, too", at this point he's just done with the conversation. The scene is pretty clear, his face reads "there's not enough gold in the world to make this worthwhile", and so he gives her the answer he thinks she wants. This is something anyone would do if they were fed up and not paying attention, you just answer with what you think the other person wants to hear.

The real issue is that while the Doppler knows Mousesack loves Ciri, he's not willing to pretend to do the same. He just gets more and more annoyed with her until he drops the act entirely and tries to kill her.

Comment: So don't "ask the right question", just ask *all* the questions...